# Can we get course start callback and complete callback response from moodle to our system?

Tags: php, laravel, moodle, moodle-api

When a student starts a course in moodle, we need to update our system with the  date with which they started the course. So we need to get a response from moodle to update that in our system, same for course completion.

Comment: Have you tried some code? https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Core_APIs

Comment: SO is not a free-coding agency. Please provide us with your code and explain where you are stuck and we can pick it up from there and help you out but no one in this community will code it for you if you don't prove at least some effort

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get first course access in moodle 3+. This action is not logged anymore, you can only get last access (unless you are on an older Moodle).

You can get the last access date to a course by querying the mdl_logstore_standard_log for the event "\core\event\course_viewed" event.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE eventname = '\\core\\event\\course_viewed' AND userid=?
```

To get the course completed date, you can search for event "\core\event\course_completed". for example:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE eventname = '\\core\\event\\course_completed' AND userid=?
```

If you want to get the date they were enrolled, you can use this query:

```
SELECT u.username, u.lastname, u.firstname, c.fullname, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'DateAndTimeCreated' FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue LEFT JOIN mdl_enrol e ON (ue.enrolid = e.id) LEFT JOIN mdl_course c ON (e.courseid = c.id) LEFT JOIN mdl_user u ON (ue.userid = u.id)
```

I would recommend creating a local plugin and using cron to check for changes and push them into your system.